# CSS Grid: side menu bar after collapse dose not change second column width automatically

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning CSS grid and I have a simple **.container** grid with 3 rows (header, navbar , footer).

**.navbar** grid area have a .sidebar and .main grid areas .

I want to click on a hidden check box and change the width of sidebar grid area and want that main grid area automatically takes the remaining width

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 10% auto ;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"   
    "navbar"    
    "footer";
}


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: none;   
  grid-gap: 0.1rem;
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 60%;
  color: var(--white);
  align-content: center;
}

.navbar
{
  grid-area: navbar;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
  grid-template-columns: var(--side-menu-width) auto;
  grid-template-areas:"sidebar main"
 
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;  
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 65% 20%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  border:none;
} 


.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar {
  left: 8rem;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 16px;
  --unit: 1rem;
  --font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  --font-weight: normal;
  --font-color: #212529;
  --white: #fff;
  --primary-color: #0076d6;
  --primary-hover: #005ea2;
  --secondary-color: #71767a;
  --secondary-hover: #565c65;
  --danger-color: #b50909;
  --danger-hover: #8b0a03;
  --success-color: #146947;
  --success-hover: #105439;
  --warning-color: #ffbe2e;
  --dark-gray: #3d4551;
  --medium-gray: #a9aeb1;
  --light-gray: #dfe1e2;
  --pale-gray-base: #edeff0;
  --pale-gray-4: #f1f3f6;
  --pale-gray-3: #f5f6f7;
  --pale-blue: #e8f5ff;
  --light-blue: #cfe8ff;
  --dark-blue: #0b4778;
  --light-indigo: #dee5ff;
  --pale-indigo: #edf0ff;
  --pale-red: #fff3f2;
  --gold: #ffbe2e;
  --light-gold: #ffe396;
  --pale-gold: #fef0c8;
  --light-green: #c7efe2;
  --pale-green: #e0f7f6;
  --fast-transition: 0.3s;
  --normal-transition: 0.5s;
  --slow-transition: 0.7s;
  --strong-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #0000001a;
  --default-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #0000000f;
  --subtle-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #00000008;
  --reduce-drag-menu: 0px;
  --reduce-main-menu: 0px;
  --reduce-submenu: 0px;
  --side-submenu-width: 270px;
  --side-menu-width: 16rem;
  --side-drag-width: 20px;
  --top-nav-height: 20px;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
  margin-top: 0;;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 10% auto ;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"   
    "navbar"    
    "footer";
}
.container div {
 
   border: var(--strong-box-shadow) solid;  
}


/* Header  */

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: none;   
  grid-gap: 0.1rem;
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 60%;
  color: var(--white);
  align-content: center;
}

.navbar
{
  grid-area: navbar;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
  grid-template-columns: var(--side-menu-width) auto;
  grid-template-areas:"sidebar main"
 
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;  
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 65% 20%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  border:none;
} 

.social-icons-list{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  height: 35rem;
}


.social-link-listitem{
  
  font-size: 1.2rem; 
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  
}

.social-link-listitem:hover{
  background: var(--light-indigo);  
  color: var(--dark-blue);
  
} 

.social-link{
  color: var(--white);  
  transition: color .4s ease;  

}

.social-link:hover
{
 color: var(--dark-blue);
} 

.social-link i{
  min-width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  
}


.social-link-listitem .tooltip
{
position: absolute;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
border-radius: .5rem;
height: 3rem;
align-items: center;
background: var(--white);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
left: 12rem;
transition: 0s;
width: var(--side-menu-width);
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}

.social-link-listitem:hover .tooltip
{
  transition: all .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Profile setting*/
.profile_content
{
  grid-row: 3;
  color : var(--white);  
  height: 4rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;

}
.profile_content .profile .profile_details{
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
  
}

.profile_content .profile .profile_img{
  
  
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: var(--white);
}


.main {
 
  grid-area: main;
  background:#105439;
  
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background:#0076d6;
}


.header-icon { 
  text-align: center; 
}

.header-text{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    
}

.header-confidential{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.user-image {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;  
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
}

/* end of Header  */



.menu-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.menu-icon:hover .line{
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.line{
  height: .2rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: .6rem;
}

.line-1 , .line-3
{
  width: 1.8rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}



.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar {
  left: 8rem;
  width: 5rem;
}


.checkbox:checked ~ .main {
  width: 5rem;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-1 {
  transform: rotate(-405deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-3 {
  transform: rotate(405deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  width: 2.5rem;
}

/* end navbar  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SIR Data Preparation</title>
    
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./images/iaea_small.png" >
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sir-style1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
    

    <div class="container">
      
            
            <div class="header"> <div class="header-icon">
                <img src="./images/iaea_small.png" alt>
            </div>
            <div class="header-text">SIR Data Preparation</div>
            <div class="header-confidential">HIGHLY CONFIDENTIAL</div> 
            
        
        </div>
            
             <!-- navbar  -->
        <div class="navbar">

            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="click" hidden>

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
               
                <label for="click">
                    <div class="menu-icon">
                        <div class="line line-1"></div>
                        <div class="line line-2"></div>
                        <div class="line line-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <ul class="social-icons-list">
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-house-user"></i>Dashboard</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>Worksheets</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Worksheets</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-signal"></i>Live Dashboard</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Live Dashboard</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Scheduler</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Scheduler</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"> <i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i>Settings</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Settings</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-hire-a-helper"></i>Help</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Help</span>
                    </li>

                   
                </ul>
                <div class="profile_content">
                    <div class="profile">
                        <div class="profile_details">
    
                        <img class="profile_img" src="./images/iaea_small.png"/>
                        <div class="name_job">
                            <div class="name">Yashveer Singh</div>
                            <div class="job">Developer</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
          
            <div class="main">Main</div>
            <!-- end of sidebar -->
            

        </div>                
          
           
       

        <div class="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"   
    "navbar"    
    "footer";
}


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: none;   
  grid-gap: 0.1rem;
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 60%;
  color: var(--white);
  align-content: center;
}

.navbar
{
  grid-area: navbar;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
  grid-template-columns: var(--side-menu-width) auto;
  grid-template-areas:"sidebar main"
 
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;  
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 65% 20%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  border:none;
} 


.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar {
  left: 8rem;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/3597276) or another code editor (such as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)). It's better if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin : I have already added snippet and I checked again and I can reproduce the issue in the snippet window are you not able to see "Run Code Snippet button"?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin let me know if you want me to do anything else ? I have added snippet please confirm if you can see it ?

Answer (score 1):

I edited your snippet, there was some little issues so your code couldn't work:

- You specified a fixed width when creating you columns then you tried to resize them, a column with a fixed width of height need an override of the `grid-template-rows` and / or `grid-template-columns` to work.
- Since we needed to update the value of `grid-template-columns` the button need to be sibbling not child of the navbar div.

[image]

But you where close to something that work, here is the reworked version :

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 16px;
  --unit: 1rem;
  --font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  --font-weight: normal;
  --font-color: #212529;
  --white: #fff;
  --primary-color: #0076d6;
  --primary-hover: #005ea2;
  --secondary-color: #71767a;
  --secondary-hover: #565c65;
  --danger-color: #b50909;
  --danger-hover: #8b0a03;
  --success-color: #146947;
  --success-hover: #105439;
  --warning-color: #ffbe2e;
  --dark-gray: #3d4551;
  --medium-gray: #a9aeb1;
  --light-gray: #dfe1e2;
  --pale-gray-base: #edeff0;
  --pale-gray-4: #f1f3f6;
  --pale-gray-3: #f5f6f7;
  --pale-blue: #e8f5ff;
  --light-blue: #cfe8ff;
  --dark-blue: #0b4778;
  --light-indigo: #dee5ff;
  --pale-indigo: #edf0ff;
  --pale-red: #fff3f2;
  --gold: #ffbe2e;
  --light-gold: #ffe396;
  --pale-gold: #fef0c8;
  --light-green: #c7efe2;
  --pale-green: #e0f7f6;
  --fast-transition: 0.3s;
  --normal-transition: 0.5s;
  --slow-transition: 0.7s;
  --strong-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #0000001a;
  --default-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #0000000f;
  --subtle-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #00000008;
  --reduce-drag-menu: 0px;
  --reduce-main-menu: 0px;
  --reduce-submenu: 0px;
  --side-submenu-width: 270px;
  --side-menu-width: 16rem;
  --side-menu-width-reduced: 5rem;
  --side-drag-width: 20px;
  --top-nav-height: 20px;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
  margin-top: 0;;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 10% auto ;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"   
    "navbar"    
    "footer";
}
.container div {
 
   border: var(--strong-box-shadow) solid;  
}


/* Header  */

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: none;   
  grid-gap: 0.1rem;
  background-color: var(--dark-blue);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 30% 60%;
  color: var(--white);
  align-content: center;
}

.navbar
{
  grid-area: navbar;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1);
  grid-template-columns: var(--side-menu-width) 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:"sidebar main"
 
}

.sidebar {
  display: grid;  
  grid-area: sidebar;
  grid-template-rows: 15% 65% 20%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  border:none;
} 

.social-icons-list{
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  height: 35rem;
}


.social-link-listitem{
  
  font-size: 1.2rem; 
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  
}

.social-link-listitem:hover{
  background: var(--light-indigo);  
  color: var(--dark-blue);
  
} 

.social-link{
  color: var(--white);  
  transition: color .4s ease;  

}

.social-link:hover
{
 color: var(--dark-blue);
} 

.social-link i{
  min-width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  
}


.social-link-listitem .tooltip
{
position: absolute;
transform: translateY(-50%);
text-align: center;
border-radius: .5rem;
height: 3rem;
align-items: center;
background: var(--white);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
left: 12rem;
transition: 0s;
width: var(--side-menu-width);
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}

.social-link-listitem:hover .tooltip
{
  transition: all .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Profile setting*/
.profile_content
{
  grid-row: 3;
  color : var(--white);  
  height: 4rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;

}
.profile_content .profile .profile_details{
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-rows: 1;
  
}

.profile_content .profile .profile_img{
  
  
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: var(--white);
}


.main {
 
  grid-area: main;
  background:#105439;
  
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background:#0076d6;
}


.header-icon { 
  text-align: center; 
}

.header-text{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    
}

.header-confidential{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.user-image {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;  
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
}

/* end of Header  */



.menu-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.menu-icon:hover .line{
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.line{
  height: .2rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: .6rem;
}

.line-1 , .line-3
{
  width: 1.8rem;
  transition: all .3s;
}


.checkbox:checked ~ .navbar {
  grid-template-columns: var(--side-menu-width-reduced) 1fr;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-1 {
  transform: rotate(-405deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .sidebar .line-3 {
  transform: rotate(405deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  width: 2.5rem;
}

/* end navbar  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SIR Data Preparation</title>
    
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./images/iaea_small.png" >
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sir-style1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
    

    <div class="container">
      
            
            <div class="header"> <div class="header-icon">
                <img src="./images/iaea_small.png" alt>
            </div>
            <div class="header-text">SIR Data Preparation</div>
            <div class="header-confidential">HIGHLY CONFIDENTIAL</div> 
            
        
        </div>
            
             <!-- navbar  -->
       <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="click" hidden>
        <div class="navbar">

            

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
               
                <label for="click">
                    <div class="menu-icon">
                        <div class="line line-1"></div>
                        <div class="line line-2"></div>
                        <div class="line line-3"></div>
                    </div>
                </label>

                <ul class="social-icons-list">
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-house-user"></i>Dashboard</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i>Worksheets</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Worksheets</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-signal"></i>Live Dashboard</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Live Dashboard</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Scheduler</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Scheduler</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"> <i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i>Settings</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Settings</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="social-link-listitem">
                        <a href="#" class="social-link"><i class="fab fa-hire-a-helper"></i>Help</a>
                        <span class="tooltip">Help</span>
                    </li>

                   
                </ul>
                <div class="profile_content">
                    <div class="profile">
                        <div class="profile_details">
    
                        <img class="profile_img" src="./images/iaea_small.png"/>
                        <div class="name_job">
                            <div class="name">Yashveer Singh</div>
                            <div class="job">Developer</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
          
            <div class="main">Main</div>
            <!-- end of sidebar -->
            

        </div>                
          
           
       

        <div class="footer">Footer</div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check the diff to better understand the modifications : https://www.diffchecker.com/qamU3z5W (1 month available online)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and explanation.